# Position QWidgets in toolbar with PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, position, toolbar

I am trying to position some buttons in a toolbar, on my application. As you can see in these images, I need to put one of them in the right side, opposing the others. Something, like this:

This is the toolbar that I have:
[image: This is the toolbar]

And I need to move, for example, the `QLabel` to the right side:
[image]

Is there any way to do this? I've tried `setGeometry` and `move` methods, but I can't accomplish this.
 Hope you can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an expanding spacer widget before the label:

```
spacer = QtGui.QWidget(self)
spacer.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
toolbar.addWidget(spacer)
toolbar.addWidget(label)
```